# How can I write on new lines in a text file while preserving old ones

Tags: python, text-files

When I open a text file and write in it and at the end of the program close it, the lines stay in the text file. When i reopen that program, rather than writing on a new set of lines, it overwrites what is already there. I want to keep both pieces of text, it is for data logging. Any ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: Open the file in append mode. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `a` mode, like this:

```
with open("file","a") as f:
    f.write("Something")
```

This will append to the file instead of overwriting it.